# Unexpected space between DIV elements

Tags: php, css, html

my code for the php page displaying the divs

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once("classlib/mainspace.php");

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])==FALSE) {
  header("location:login.php");
}
$user = new User($_SESSION['username']);
?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" />
  <title>SimpleTask - Home</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="menu">
        <div id="items">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="home.php">home</a></li>
            <li>&bull;</li>
            <li><a href="projects.php">my projects</a></li>
            <li>&bull;</li>
            <li><a href="comments.php">my comments</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="user">
          <p>Welcome, <?php echo $user->GetRealName(); ?><br/><a href="editprofile.php">edit profile</a> &bull; <a href="logout.php">logout</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="content">
        <h1>HOME</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
      <p>footer text goes here here here here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and you can find my CSS here http://tasker.efficaxdevelopment.com/style/style.css

and to view the live page go here http://tasker.efficaxdevelopment.com/login.php

username:admin
password:password

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add:

```
h1,p {
margin:0;
}
```

Those elements and a few others have margins and paddings by default.

Comment: @jon I guess you should change the title then.